# Are questions about amusement park rides on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently asked [a question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83368/mission-space-orange-and-male-pattern-baldness/83376) about an amusement park ride and it was closed because it was "unclear what I was asking". In one of the more up-voted comments people were also saying that my question had nothing to do with travel.

I've since deleted the question as it was a lightning rod for down votes and altho I think it /was/, in fact, quite clear what I was asking, that's neither here nor there.

What I'm specifically curious about w.r.t. this post are the claims that the question had nothing to do with travel.

Are questions about amusement park rides on topic?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as long as there is a reasonable connection to travel.

This question was about an attraction that people travel to, specifically about understanding a travel article describing it. It's no different than asking about tickets or transportation at Disney World. I see no reason it should have been closed, and it was certainly not unclear.

Frankly, the two minutes it took me to answer the question seems like a far more useful activity than the amount of effort people put into arguing it should be closed.

Comment: I didn't know that deleted questions were still visible lol. Is that a feature that 10k rep points unlocks?

Comment: @neubert I think it's at 10k yeah.

Comment: @pnuts I don't understand that question and would vote to close it as unclear if it was asked without any further details.